# Microsoft API to export MYSQL data to Microsoft project

Tags: php, ms-project

I am required to generate a Microsoft project file with some data MYSQL database. Since the application I am writing is a PHP application, is there a way to create a Microsoft project file like we do data export to excel file using some libraries. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) to create eiter MPX or MSPDI files which can be read by Microsoft Project. You can do this directly from PHP using the [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).

Jon

p.s. Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's an [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738433.aspx) that shows how to import from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to do it via C# and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.dll.

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public static class ProjectHelper
    {
        public static void CreateProject(string projectName, DataSet mySqlData)
        {
            ApplicationClass msProjectApp = new ApplicationClass();
            msProjectApp.AppMaximize();
            msProjectApp.FileNew(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            Project project = msProjectApp.ActiveProject;

            // Process the dataset and add tasks ... etc
            // Assume you are reading from the dataset

            Task task = project.Tasks.Add("test1", 1);
            Task task2 = project.Tasks.Add("test2", 2);

            task.Start = "22/10/2009";
            task.Finish = "25/10/2009";

            task.Text1 = "some test";
            msProjectApp.GanttBarFormat(task.ID, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjColor.pjGreen, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            task2.Start = "23/10/2009";
            task2.Finish = "24/03/2009";

            task2.Text1 = "some test 2";
            task2.Predecessors = task.ID.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```